# Sitecore 9.1.1 upgrade

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

I have a Sitecore 8.2 project that I'm upgrading to 9.1.1. I installed a fresh insistence of Sitecore 9.1.1 and moved my old project into it. I have it pointing at the old Core, Master, Web databases and everything seems to be running good. My question is should i still install the "upgrade package"? Do i need to upgrade my databases at all?

Comment: **Yes**! You absolutely **must** follow the entire upgrade guide that you can find on https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/91/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_91_Update1.aspx This is absolutely **CRITICAL**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I typically do upgrades...this is a bit simplistic, as it may get expansive based on your environment(s):

1. Install the **current** Sitecore instance and connect the existing databases (core and master) to it. Do NOT publish custom code to this.
2. Run the Sitecore upgrade package so that your databases get the updates they need.
3. Install the **new** Sitecore instance and connect the upgraded core and master databases. (You don't need web, since that's just published out from the master.)
4. In your codebase, update the appropriate packages and configs. Assuming you used transforms and didn't modify your base web.config from what Sitecore delivers, this should be easier. Going from 8.x to 9.x, you also need to account for the use of roles, which can make it so you convert transforms on App_Config/Include files to just use roles.
5. Handle any other code changes, deprecated calls, upgrading Glass Mapper, etc etc as needed.
6. Publish your upgraded code to the **new** instance and start testing.

That's very high level but should get you started. This way you keep your existing instance in the event of issues, as well.

Comment: I like that method of doing upgrades.  I have always found doing upgrades for sitecore a painful process.  I've done something similar but to your method but I never installed the a current instance. I would just install a fresh copy of the new instance, upgrade only the db then migrate the custom configurations, dll, etc.  I am in the process of upgrading to 911 and I am going to try to use your method.

Comment: Using the current instance is to have the site and db be "matching" so Sitecore is, in theory, doing an in-place upgrade. You're just dumping the site afterwards. It's an extra step but you're not cross-version at any point in theory.